# how to get a list of char from user input in ocaml

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml, user-input

I cannot find a way to get a list from values given by the user. I already did

```
  # read_line() |> Str.split (Str.regexp " +") |> List.map int_of_string;;
```

but don't know how to do the same for chars.

Answer (score 1):

just remember that a string is an array of char:

```
  # let s = "ab";;
  # s.[0];;
  - : char = 'a'
```

So, if you have to return a char for any of the elements of your list :

```
 #  read_line() |> Str.split (Str.regexp " +") |> List.map (fun x -> x.[0])
```

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, a string is not an array of chars, the latter is `[|a;b;c|]`. And it is access with the `x.(i)` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

From the context of your previous questions, you seem to actually need a way to parse text that contains a mix of integers and characters that describe the transitions for a state machine. I'd suggest that you may be best served with the `Scanf` module for this. If you need something much more complex, though, this may require a handwritten scanner (you can use `Str.string_match` for that or – if you're willing to dive that deep – use the `ocamllex` scanner generator).

A simple example of reading a line from a channel with Scanf would be:

```
let read_transition input =
  try
    let line = input_line input in
    Scanf.sscanf line "%d %c %d"
      (fun x ch y -> Some (x, ch, y))
  with End_of_file -> None
```

Note that we're reading the line with `input_line` rather than using `Scanf.scanf` on the input channel directly. The reason is that `Scanf.scanf` may need up to a character worth of lookahead and thus, if you mix it with other ways of reading the channel, characters may get skipped. By using `input_line` and then `Scanf.sscanf` (rather than `Scanf.scanf`) we avoid that corner case.

Note also that depending on the syntax of the input, you may have to adjust the scanf pattern accordingly.

Comment: thanks that's exactly what i want but according to this suggestion of yours i would need a function that will split the read line and feed it to this function to get the list of transitions that i want right?

Comment: You will need to iterate over the input channel (e.g. `stdin`) until you get `None`. You can do this with a while loop or a recursive function.